# How to create standalone python script for OS X from Windows10/Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, osx-yosemite

I have a Python (2.7.11) project created in Eclipse on Windows 10 that I want to run on OS X. [This does not answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721882/export-runnable-program-from-python-eclipse-project-on-ubuntu/6721912#6721912) my question because it tells how to create an exe on windows and an executable on OS X (using py2app). I tried to install py2app on the Windows 10 machine, but that doesn't work. How do I do this?

Comment: I haven't used http://www.pyinstaller.org/ myself, but it looks like it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an OS X app in Windows 10. You'll have to setup a python environment on OS X equal to the one in Windows 10, and copy the code over and use `py2app` or `pyinstaller` in OS X.

Comment: This is what I've had to do. Installed Eclipse/PyDev then copied the code,

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a Mac, but on Linux I just make the script executable.

```
$chmod u+x myscript.py
```

Then I add this to the header of myscript.py where /usr/bin/python is the path to the python binary.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Thanks for this, though I think it won't work for me because I have a 'project', with more than one .py file.

Comment: If you distribute all the source code files your main script can still do all the imports you need.